# NY Subway: What does it mean if a train stop is greyed out?

Tags: trains, new-york-city

From a metro map I picked up in NYC:

[image]

The Cortlandt St stop was greyed out.  I happened to wander near the station near the WTC Memorial, but it seems it was locked for some unknown reason.

What does it mean if it's greyed out? The map's Legend doesn't seem to indicate what a gray stop represents.

Comment: If you'd like to visit that station now, it opened at the beginning of this week.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means the station is closed.  In this case, the station was closed after it was destroyed on September 11, 2001, and it has not yet been reopened.  I believe it will be reopened sometime in the next few years as construction is completed on the site.

---

Update: The station reopened on September 10, 2018.

Comment: That's weird though. When I was near the WTC Memorial Center, and looking for the nearest subway, I asked a few cops how to get to the Cortlandt St. Subway, and they all told me where to go, but they never indicated it was closed in any way

Comment: There is an open Cortlandt Street station on another line -- the R line.  It's very close to the closed one on the 1 line.

Comment: @thinlyveiledquestionmark you're welcome.  The Cortlandt St station on the R (which was also closed for some time) is labeled "Essex" on your map; for some reason the station names have been replaced with coffee shops' names.

Comment: @phoog There are a whole series of maps by various people of various cities suggesting bars, restaurants, etc. by subway or metro stop. This one was [posted on Reddit by rickymikeabono](http://www.reddit.com/r/nyc/comments/1x1kel/manhattans_best_coffeehouses_by_subway_stop/).

Answer (score 4):

*edit: phoog beat me to the short answer, but offers less background.*

If you look up the 1 Train at the MTA website, you'll see that it does not stop at Cortlandt St as that station is [temporarily closed](http://web.mta.info/nyct/service/oneline.htm).

After the September 11 attacks, a number of subway stations were closed. Their treatment in subsequent maps is presented clearly [on Brian Abbott's blog](http://brianabbott.net/observations/2004/09/11/september-11-three-years-later):

- In the first maps issued after September 11, the closed stations were removed from the map entirely
- By October, most service had been restored, and suspended service indicated with dotted lines
- In December 2001, the closed stations were represented as grayed out

Most service was restored by October 2002, but the Cortlandt St stop remains closed, and so remains on the map as grayed out pending reconstruction of the World Trade Center area.

--

The station finally [re-opened as WTC Cortlandt St.](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/09/08/nyregion/cortlandt-street-subway-station-911.html) in 2018, with 1 Train service, and is accessible via an underpass from the [WTC Transportation Hub](https://www.panynj.gov/wtcprogress/transportation-hub.html).

Comment: The station reopened earlier this week.

Comment: Once again, you have more detail than I do.  I overlooked the name change.